# How to remove unneeded white spaces and last word of a string with Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains words in a pattern like this:

```
  2013-2014  XXX 29 
  2011-2012  XXXX 44
```

Please note that there are 2 whitespaces before AND after the year.
I need to remove the first 2 whitespaces, the 1 whitespace after the year and the last word (29/44 etc).
So it will become like this:

```
2013-2014 XXX
2011-2012 XXXX
```

Im really bad with Regex so any help would be appreciated. So far i can remove the last word with

```
str.replaceAll(" [^ ]+$", "");
```

Comment: Is it OK to replace all two or more spaces with one?

Comment: The first two white spaces must be removed completely. But let one white space after the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only what you want and replace the rest (with a space in the middle) :)
This should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s1 = "  2013-2014  XXX 29 ";
    System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("^\\s+([\\d-]+)\\s+(\\w+).*", "$1 $2"));

    String s2 = "  2011-2012  XXXX 44 ";
    System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("^\\s+([\\d-]+)\\s+(\\w+).*", "$1 $2"));
}
```

O/P :

```
2013-2014 XXX
2011-2012 XXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regex for this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^ +|(?<=\\d{4} ) | [^ ]+ *$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK2vJ2/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^ +             # 1 or more spaces at start
|               # OR
(?<=\\d{4} )    # space after 4 digit year and a space
|               # OR
 [^ ]+ *$       # text after last space at end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it in multiple more easy to understand steps, like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    String s = "  2011-2012  XXXX 44";
    // Remove leading and trailing whitespace
    s = s.trim();
    System.out.println(s);
    // replace two or more whitespaces with a single whitespace
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
    System.out.println(s);
    // remove the last word and the whitespace before it
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s\\w*$", "");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P:

```
2011-2012  XXXX 44
2011-2012 XXXX 44
2011-2012 XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ").trim();
```

---

Example:

```
String str = "  2013-2014  XXX 29 ";
```

Now:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ");
```

Output: `" 2013-2014 XXX 29 "`

And with `.trim()` it looks like this: `"2013-2014 XXX 29"`